# Is .NET Socket Send()/Receive() thread-safe?

Tags: .net, sockets, multithreading

Since a socket is full duplexed, meaning you can send and recieve simultaneously. So, is the .NET Socket Send()/Receive() thread-safe? I need to Send() and Receive() in 2 threads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quote from the [MSDN docs about the Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) (under *Thread Safety*, towards the end of the page):

> Instances of this class are thread
>   safe.

So I would suppose the answer is "yes".